# My new installation of SQL Server Management Studio 18.2 have a trouble with its UI

Tags: windows-10, sql-server, ssms

Every time I start the applications it's UI is disappearing. Like this [Disappearing UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzpUe.png), or like this [Disappearing UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBLZJ.png)

Please help me to solve that problem. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: UI come back when maximize or resize the app.

Comment: I've to found answer on twitter. Just try opening Tools\Options and uncheck the "Automatically adjust visual experience" checkbox, and uncheck "Use hardware graphics acceleration"(@shueybubbles)

Answer (score 0):

I've to found answer on twitter. Just try opening Tools\Options and uncheck the "Automatically adjust visual experience" checkbox, and uncheck "Use hardware graphics acceleration"(@shueybubbles)